# Heroku Django Logging

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to debug an internal server error in my django app, running on heroku. I'm 
completely new to all of this web server stuff so I really have no idea what to do.

It seems like the stdout output is sometimes getting logged in heroku logs and sometimes not. I was reasonably sure that the program was reaching a certain line but the prints at that point are simply not showing up.

I am seeing the 500 error in my heroku logs file, but there is no stack trace or anything else in there. I am trying to create a web server to respond to GET and POST requests from various applications I have running, meaning I don't know how to debug this in a web browser, if thats even applicable. The current error is on a POST request sent to the webserver. I can't replicate this locally because the Http module I am using, http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/ seems to be unable to connect to a local ip address.

I have done some extensive googling for the last hour and I haven't found any help. Do I need to enable logging or something somewhere in heroku? I am completely new to this so please be explicit in your explanations. I have heard mention of a way to get stack traces emailed to you but I haven't seen an explanation of how to do that. is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend 2 things in this case:
First: use python's logging facility rather than print statements (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html).  This gives you much more control over where your statements end up, and allows you to filter them.

Second: use a logging add-on.  This vastly increases the amount of logging you can store (loggly keeps all your logs for 24 hours even in the "free" size), so you don't have to worry about the relevant information falling out before you get around to looking at it.